# Why second debugger inside Ajax don't work while testing in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript-debugger

I created an Ajax call & tried to debug its success & failure in chrome using `debugger;`.

The first debugger statement works properly but the flow is not stopping at the second debugger statement and instead I see following in sources panel:

```
<script type="text/javascript"  id="debugbar_loader" data-time="1611085354" src="http://localhost/my_project/public/?debugbar"></script><script type="text/javascript"  id="debugbar_dynamic_script"></script><style type="text/css"  id="debugbar_dynamic_style"></style>
```

Ajax is also working properly as I receive POST data in server. Kindly advise.

```html
<form action="#" method="POST">
  <button type="submit" name="submit_form" class="btn" id="submit_form">Save Changes</button>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // First Debugger
  debugger;
  
  $("#submit_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fd = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    // Second Debugger
    debugger;

    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: fd,
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      },
    });
  });
});
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ctree/qoac8ntd/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the `submit` event fires on the `form` element, not the `button` you've selected.

In fact the entire `submit` handler assumes that `this` refers to the `form` element, given you use of `attr('action')` and passing the reference to the `FormData()` constructor.

Also note that if you're sending FormData in the AJAX request then you will also need to include `processData: false` and `contentType: false` in the AJAX options.

With all that said, try this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="POST" id="submit_form">
  <button type="submit" name="submit_form" class="btn">Save Changes</button>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('A'); // debugger

  $("#submit_form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fd = new FormData(this);
    var url = this.action;

    console.log('B'); // debugger
    
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: fd,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    });
  });
});
```